# Symmetric product of Zariski cotangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ a commutative ring, $M\subset A$ a maximal ideal, $k=A/M$ the residual field at $M$ and $T=M/M^2$ the Zariski cotangent space at $M$. In terms of regular functions, $T$ is made of the order-1 terms. The order-2 terms are this other $k$-vector space $U=M^2/M^3$. There is an obvious $k$-linear and surjective map $\varphi : T\otimes_k T \to U$ defined by $\varphi(x\otimes_k y) = xy$. And since $M^2$ is commutative, the kernel of $\varphi$ includes all tensors $x\otimes_k y - y\otimes_k x$. In other words, $\varphi$ induces a $k$-linear and surjective map from the symmetric product of $T$ into $U$. Is this an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces?

In the case where the dimension of the $k$-vector space $T$ is finite, equal to $n$, it suffices to count dimensions. The dimension of the symmetric product of $T$ is $n(n+1)/2$. So we already have this upper bound for the dimension of $U$, and the question reduces to proving equality to that bound.

In the case where $A$ is the polynomial ring over a field $k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$, and $M$ is the ideal of polynomials that vanish at 0, it works because the second-order polynomials $(X_i X_j)_{i\leq j}$ are $k$-linearly independent.

Also, does this generalize to order-r terms $M^r/M^{r+1}$?

Comment: What if $M^2=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804451/symmetric-powers-of-ideal-quotients-in-a-local-ring) gives sufficient conditions, namely it is enough that $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay and that $M$ is generated by a regular sequence, see Theorem 8.21A(e) in Hartshorne, or that $I$ is of linear type, i.e., that $\mathrm{Sym}(I) \simeq R(I)$, where $R(I) = \oplus_{n \geq 0} I^n$ is the Rees algebra of $I$, see the comment in the linked question.

Comment: When the answer is "look at this answer over here", it would be better to flag the question as a duplicate of that.